Spring Data Neo4j Composition
I want to implement using a class as composition.
For example:
public class Person {
  String name;
  Integer age;
}

@Node("Student")
public class Student {
  Person person;
  String school;
}

@Node("Manager")
public class Manager {
  Person person;
  String job;
}

Given the code above, I would like the Student node to have school and properties of Person (name, age).
I’ve seen @CompositeProperty, but since it requires using a Map, it’s different from what I want to achieve.
This could be represented with an IS-A relationship, but that might make the relationships more complex. Instead, I want to store them as properties. Is there a way to implement this?

Crosspost on Spring Data Neo4j's GitHub repo
